# Laggy Output to Console

Tags: c++, winapi, ascii

I have been trying to make asteroids in the console, I know that the console isn't an ideal way to do this, but I wanted to challenge myself.

The problem I am having is with printing to the screen. At first, my screen was flickering because I wasn't updating certain screen parts and instead redrawing every frame by appending the whole array to a string and outputting that string.

So I changed my code to do that, but my current problem now is that the fps of my game is really low because I can't batch call it to one cout function.

To print my code to the screen I have a 2d array of characters with width and height as its size. Then I copy the array, change the output, and compare it to the previous output to see if the pixel needs to be changed, then change it.

Here is my draw function

```
void draw() {
    char prevOutput[ArrayBorder][ArrayBorder];
    copyOutput(outputBuffer, prevOutput);
    innitOutput();
    plotPolygons();
    for (int y = 0; y < GameBorder; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < GameBorder; x++) {
            if (outputBuffer[x][y] == prevOutput[x][y]) {continue;}
            setCursorPosition(x, y);
            cout << outputBuffer[x][y];
        }
    }
    cout.flush();
}
```

Here is my previous draw function

```
void draw() {
    innitOutput();
    plotPolygons();
    system("CLS");
    string output = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < GameBorder; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < GameBorder; x++) {
            output += outputBuffer[x][y];
        }
        output += "\n";
    }
    cout << output;
}
```

Comment: So originally you were making an array of characters the same size as the screen and calling cout to write the entire screen and you changed it so that you only write the parts that have changed?  Maybe the first way is better except cout is buffered and when writing interactively it is line buffered so it flushes when it gets to a newline.  If you could turn off the buffering and call std::endl only at the end of writing the whole screen it might write faster because it would be one screenful at a time with one flush.

Comment: C++' I/O streams library has the worst imaginable performance. See [Using the Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console) for a native API.

Comment: @IInspectable Would you recommend using the WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() from the Windows Console API?